# Why is @ObservableObject View Model Reset When Timer.TimerPublisher Fires?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have a type that vends a `Timer.TimerPublisher`, which you can see below:

```swift
import Combine
import Foundation

struct TimerClient {

    // MARK: Properties

    var timerValueChange: () -> AnyPublisher<Date, Never>

    // MARK: Initialization

    init(
        timerValueChange: @escaping () -> AnyPublisher<Date, Never>
    ) {
        self.timerValueChange = timerValueChange
    }
}

extension TimerClient {

    // MARK: Properties

    static var live: Self {
        Self {
            return Timer
                .TimerPublisher(
                    interval: 1,
                    runLoop: .main,
                    mode: .common
                )
                .autoconnect()
                .share()
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }

}
```

I have a `View` that is used to save new events. It is injected with a view model that uses `TimerClient` so that I can disable the `Save` button if users attempt to save an event with a past date:

```
import Combine

final class CountdownEventEntryViewModel: ObservableObject {

    // MARK: Properties

    private let nowSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Date, Never>(Date())

    private let calendar: Calendar
    private let timerClient: TimerClient

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    @Published var eventTitle = ""
    @Published var isAllDay = false
    @Published var eventDate = Date()
    @Published var eventTime = Date()
    @Published var shouldDisableSaveButton = true

    // MARK: Initialization
    
    init(
        calendar: Calendar = .autoupdatingCurrent,
        timerClient: TimerClient
    ) {
        self.calendar = calendar
        self.timerClient = timerClient
        observeTimer()
        observeCurrentDateChanges()
    }

    // MARK: UI Configuration

    private func disableSaveButton() -> Bool {
        if eventTitle.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty {
            return true
        }
        if isAllDay {
            let startOfToday = calendar.startOfDay(for: nowSubject.value)
            let startOfSelectedDate = calendar.startOfDay(for: eventDate)
            return startOfSelectedDate <= startOfToday
        } else {
            return normalizedSelectedDate() <= nowSubject.value
        }
    }

    private func observeTimer() {
        timerClient.timerValueChange().sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] newDate in
            self?.nowSubject.send(newDate)
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

    private func observeCurrentDateChanges() {
        nowSubject.sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.shouldDisableSaveButton = self?.disableSaveButton() ?? false
        })
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }

}
```

The view model works well, and it updates the `Save` button if an attempt is made to select a past date:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CountdownEventEntryView: View {

    // MARK: Properties
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: CountdownEventEntryViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField(
                    viewModel.eventTitlePlaceholderKey,
                    text: $viewModel.eventTitle
                )
        }
            Section {
                Toggle(
                    isOn: $viewModel.isAllDay.animation(),
                    label: {
                        Text(viewModel.isAllDayLabelTextKey)
                    }
                )
                DatePicker(
                    viewModel.eventDatePickerLabelTextKey,
                    selection: $viewModel.eventDate,
                    displayedComponents: [.date]
                )
                if !viewModel.isAllDay {
                    DatePicker(
                        viewModel.eventTimePickerLabelTextKey,
                        selection: $viewModel.eventTime,
                        displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute]
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                Button {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text(viewModel.saveButtonTitleKey)
                }
                .disabled(viewModel.shouldDisableSaveButton)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

After the entry view is dismissed, the `List` that displays saved events is updated according to the following view model:

```swift
import Combine
import CoreData

final class CountdownEventsViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties

    private let calendar: Calendar
    private let timerClient: TimerClient

    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    @Published var now = Date()
    @Published var countdownEvents = [CountdownEvent]()

    // MARK: Initialization

    init(
        calendar: Calendar = .autoupdatingCurrent,
        timerClient: TimerClient
) {
        self.calendar = calendar
        self.timerClient = timerClient
        super.init()
        observeTimer()
        fetchCountdownEvents()
    }

// MARK: Timer Observation

private func observeTimer() {
    timerClient.timerValueChange().sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] newDate in
        self?.now = newDate
    })
    .store(in: &cancellables)
}

// MARK: Event Display

func formattedTitle(for event: CountdownEvent) -> String {
    event.title ?? untitledLabelKey
}

func formattedDate(for event: CountdownEvent) -> String {
    guard let date = event.date else {
        return dateUnknownLabelKey
    }
    if event.isAllDay {
        return DateFormatter.dateOnlyFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
    return DateFormatter.dateAndTimeFormatter.string(from: date)
}

func formattedTimeRemaining(from date: Date, to event: CountdownEvent) -> String {
    guard let eventDate = event.date else {
        return dateUnknownLabelKey
    }
    let allowedComponents: Set<Calendar.Component> = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
    let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(allowedComponents, from: date, to: eventDate)
    guard let formatted = DateComponentsFormatter.eventTimeRemainingFormatter.string(from: dateComponents) else {
        return dateUnknownLabelKey
    }
    return formatted
}
```

}

The view model is used in a `View` that displays all saved items in a list:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CountdownEventsView: View {

    // MARK: Properties

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: CountdownEventsViewModel

    @State private var showEventEntry = false
    @State private var now = Date()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                ForEach(viewModel.countdownEvents) { event in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(viewModel.formattedTitle(for: event))
                        Text(viewModel.formattedDate(for: event))
                        Text(viewModel.formattedTimeRemaining(from: now, to: event))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
                HStack(spacing: 30) {
                    Button(action: showSettings) {
                        Label(viewModel.settingsButtonTitleKey, systemImage: viewModel.settingsButtonImageName)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        showEventEntry = true
                    }, label: {
                        Label(
                            title: { Text(viewModel.addEventButtonTitleKey) },
                            icon: { Image(systemName: viewModel.addEventButtonImageName) }
                        )
                    })
            }
        }
        .sheet(
            isPresented: $showEventEntry,
            content: {
                NavigationView {
                    CountdownEventEntryView(
                        viewModel:
                            CountdownEventEntryViewModel(
                                timerClient: .live
                            )
                    )
                }
            }
        )
        .onReceive(viewModel.$now, perform: { now in
            self.now = now
        })
     
    }

    // MARK: Initialization

    init(viewModel: CountdownEventsViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
```

}

This works as expected, and the `Text` elements are updated with the expected values. Additionally, I am able to scroll the `List` and see the `Text` values update thanks to adding the `Timer` to the `main` runloop and `common` mode. However, when I navigate to the event-entry view, the view model seems to get reset when the timer fires.

Below, you can see that the entered text is reset with every fire of the timer:

[image]

It seems that my view model is somehow being recreated, but both view models are `@ObservableObject`s, so I am not sure why I'm seeing the values reset after the timer fires. The `DatePicker`, `Toggle`, `TextField`, and `Button` values are all reset to their defaults when the timer fires.

What am I missing that is causing the text to clear when the timer fires?

If it helps, the project is located [here](https://github.com/nickkohrn/CountdownEvents). Be sure to use the `save-countdown-events` branch. Additionally, I am modeling my client types after Point-Free's [teachings about dependency injection](https://www.pointfree.co/episodes/ep111-designing-dependencies-modularization#t911) ([code](https://github.com/pointfreeco/episode-code-samples/tree/main/0111-designing-dependencies-pt2)), if that helps provide more context.

Comment: There's honestly a lot of code here. A good approach to debug a problem is to try to isolate it by removing things that are unrelated, which not coincidentally also leads to a more focused question by way of a minimal reproducible example. Can you try to minimize it?

Comment: Also, why are you using a `Timer only to check if the time is not in the past. You don't need a timer for that; you just need to call `Date()` to get the current time and compare`

Comment: @NewDev Sure, I’ll try to reduce the code and provide a more minimized sample. I used a timer simply because I am trying to better understand Combine. I wanted to use it everywhere I can in this small project, even if it’s overkill, so that I can become more comfortable with it.